# Why isn't rspec generating specs for controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

Created a new app with `rails generate new_app -T` and ran `rails generate rspec:install`.

```
$ rails generate controller Test foo bar
      create  app/controllers/test_controller.rb
       route  get "test/bar"
       route  get "test/foo"
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/test
      create    app/views/test/foo.html.erb
      create    app/views/test/bar.html.erb
      invoke  rspec
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/test_helper.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/helpers/test_helper_spec.rb
```

- rails (3.0.0)
- rspec (2.0.0.beta.22)
- rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.22)
- rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.22)
- rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.22)
- rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.22)

For some reason the `invoke rspec` doesn't generate the Test controller spec. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue [closed](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/closed#issue/205). Beta 23 will include the fix.